# Where should I unpack additional python version

Tags: package-management, python

I was having a connection issue where the command

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/Python-2.7.14.tgz
```

wouldn't download python onto my ubuntu machine. I instead used winscp to upload this tar file (which I was able to download on my windows computer) over to the ubuntu machine. Right now it is in my `/home/username/Downloads` folder.

I plan on using this version of python in a virtual environment that I have yet to create since I needed this version. My question is where should I unpack this tar file? Should I move it over to usr/bin with the other two versions of python that came preinstalled on the machine?